# PWA installation and service worker

Tags: installation, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, manifest.json

**I've created a PWA with a service-worker that is installed when using the SDK of the firebase push notifications. Please see below manifest.json and service-worker.**
[image]

[image: manifest]

**Now I can't prompt for the app to be installed, because it gives me the error in regards to the start-url and that it is out of scope.
Can I install another service-worker simply for the prompt? The scope as seen in the pictures of the service-worker for the firebase notifications seems the be the base of the domain and not the start page of the pwa.**

**Not entirely sure how i could solve this...**
[image: lighthouse]

Here the file structure of the asp.net core project:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-service-worker#service_worker_lifecycle):

> The scope of the service worker determines which files the service worker controls, in other words, from which path the service worker will intercept requests. The default scope is the location of the service worker file, and extends to all directories below. So if service-worker.js is located in the root directory, the service worker will control requests from all files at this domain.

Right not your service worker is not at the root of the domain, so it won't cover all the domain, it is under `/firebase-cloudmessaging-push-scope` so you either serve the PWA from that scope, or move your service worker file under the PWA scope at `/Client/Dashboard`. Because it would be not only for the install prompt, for your service worker to intercept requests and messages for your PWA, they have to be in the same scope.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly. The problem is that i'm using the firebase plugin / sdk that starts the service worker for the notifications under that scope.

Comment: Can you post the file structure of your project? Is the file firebase-messaging-sw.js at the root of the project? and it contains a folder Client/Dashboard for the PWA? [Also](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-service-worker#service_worker_lifecycle)
"You can also set an arbitrary scope by passing in an additional parameter when registering. For example:" So seeing how you are registering the sw might be useful.

Comment: Yes, firebase-messaging-sw.js is at the root. Everything is working fine notification wise. I've edited my question. It's an asp.net core website with the pwa at Client/Dashboard. From there the service worker also gets initiated. It's the firebase sdk. The service worker gets registered through their sdk which is why i can't choose the scope. see here https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/firebase-web-push-notifications-26352b136814   For me it's all about the scope. That's why my question if i could just register another service-worker or can adapt the scope of the firebase sdk.